# How do I bypass restrictions on the length of the PATH variable

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

[image: error message]

> **System Properties**
>
> This environment variable is too large. This dialog allows setting values up to 2047 characters long.

I use/have used a lot of software, and my PATH has grown as a result. When I try to add new paths, I get the above message. As a workaround, I'm editing my user path, but prefer not to.

Comment: In future posts, please add the text of the error message, which I assume you already [searched for](https://superuser.com/search?q=%22This+environment+variable+is+too+large%22) to confirm the question was not asked earlier ;-) Often, just hitting Ctrl+C in such dialog will copy it for you.

Comment: Perhaps ask on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for a utility to detect duplicate entries and entries where the directory does not exist (uninstallers are lousy about updating the path). This would be trivial to code as a Python script.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation says that an environment variable on Windows is limited to
only 32,767 characters
([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/ms682653.aspx)),
but does not say how to create such a long variable.

The problem here is that the tools that Windows provides all have their
limits :

- The set and setx commands truncate values to 1023 characters.
- Setting directly in the registry at
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`
  fails since regedit truncates entered strings after 2047 characters.

So you must use workarounds.

**Use short folder names**

You may see such names by using `dir /x /ad`.
The following example shows that on my computer the folder `Program Files (x86)`
may be replaced by `PROGRA~2`:

[image]

**Use embedded environmental variables**

If you have:

```
C:\this_is_a\long_path\that_appears\in_multiple_places\subdir1
C:\this_is_a\long_path\that_appears\in_multiple_places\subdir2
```

then you can create a new environment variable such as:

```
SET P1=C:\this_is_a\long_path\that_appears\in_multiple_places
```

after which your original paths become

```
%P1%\subdir1
%P1%\subdir2
```

You may also split PATH into two by creating a new variable, say `NEWPATH`,
containing the excess paths and  append `;%NEWPATH%` to the PATH variable.

Avoid using the
[setx command](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)
because it will directly resolve embedded environmental variables
and the resulting string will be once again too long.

**Use a PowerShell script to set the PATH**

PowerShell calls Windows API directly and so can approach the theoretical limit
of 32,767 characters for an environmental variable.

The script may contain commands such as:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $longpath, "Machine")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Of all of these, the %NEWPATH% option is the most palatable, so I think I'll go with that.

Comment: Splitting into multiple env vars, such as `%NEWPATH%`, also allows me to nest other env vars in `%NEWPATH%` (string expansion I guess happens at each nested level - have not tested to see what happens in an infinite reference loop..)

Comment: also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491244/environment-variable-is-too-large-on-windows-10

Comment: I've used newpath several times it seems to be deleted in fact converted into variable and added. probably other programs adding their path

Comment: You can also use symlinks to shorten paths. Example: `mklink /J "C:\PF86" "C:\Program Files (x86)"`

Answer (score 8):

I tried this. It is working for me after [following @harrymc’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1385878/167207) even if you are facing this issue try this.

Make a new `path2` with all contents from `path`.

Now place `%path2%` inside path

[image]

[image]

So now `%path2%; %path3%; %path4%; ...` and so on.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: tried increasing using regedit ?

Comment: I have not tried, because [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1385878/875708) said it doesn't work as well. I currently temporary solution is using short path (i.e. PROGRA~1, PROGRA~2).

Comment: This is what I did, actually, and it worked fine.  I don't see where the other answer says it doesn't work and it actually implies it does.  I broke PATH up into groups, like _SYSTEM, _PROGRAM_FILES, _PROGRAM_FILES_X86, and so forth.  Then PATH became %_SYSTEM%;%_PROGRAM_FILES%;%_PROGRAM_FILES_X86%; and so forth.  This is a great way to organize and manage PATH, though you do have to watch for the correct order and conflicts as you would with PATH in any case.

Comment: this is probably the most clean solution

Comment: this works until PATH loads all the strings in %PATH1%, %PATH2%... etc and becomes too long again. I only have 5 lines in PATH and these 5 lines all reference env variables and it's already cutting off at a point.

Answer (score 3):

While the dialog that you used limits the length that environment variables to 2047 characters, the registry editor does not have that limitation.  The registry editor can be opened with the run dialog which can be opened with the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keyboard shortcut.  Typing `regedit` and pressing enter will open the registry editor.  Environment variables are listed under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Control\Session Manager\Environment` and `Path` can be found among them.  Right-clicking `Path` will open a menu, of which **Modify...** can be selected to modify the value of the variable.  As always, when working with the registry editor, make sure that you only change what you intend to, as some changes may have less than desirable side effects.

Comment: This works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new variable, path2, and place that variable in your path variable. That should work. Also, I'm using an app called PathCopy to shorten all my path names in my path. That is helping also.

I've also tested this:

```
$pathEnv = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','Machine')

$splitPaths = $pathEnv.Split(";") 
$shortPaths = @()
ForEach ($path in $splitPaths) {
    $a = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    # Try to get the short path
    try {
        $shortPath = $a.GetFolder("$path").ShortPath
        if (-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($shortPath)) {
            $shortPaths += $shortPath
        } else {
            # If short path is null or empty, use the original path
            $shortPaths += $path
        }
    } catch {
        # If an error occurs (e.g., folder does not exist), use the original path
        $shortPaths += $path
    }
}

$newPath = $shortPaths -join ";"

[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path',$newPath,'Machine')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create path2
2. put %path2% to path
3. check at cmd if work , as example python...

[image]

[image]

[image]